# Define API GATEWAY list type parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

According to the [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/making-http-requests/) it is possible to pass query parameter with list type in a format `foo=1,2,3`

But when I am doing it in that way i receive `string` instead of `array` in lambda `event.queryStringParameters.foo === '1,2,3'`

Am I missing something, or aws does not support this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Sorry I don't have enough rep to comment yet so having to submit this as an answer.*

There appears to be a new Lambda event field "multiValueQueryStringParameters".

For example the following url would generate this event in AWS Lambda:

https://example.uk/API/search?excludeLabels=sstc&excludeLabels=empty&excludeLabels=removed&limit=500

```
{
  "resource": "/{proxy+}",
  "path": "/API/search",
  "httpMethod": "GET",
  "headers": {},
  "multiValueHeaders": {},
  "queryStringParameters": {
      "excludeLabels": "removed",
      "limit": "500"
  },
  "multiValueQueryStringParameters": {
      "excludeLabels": [
          "sstc",
          "empty",
          "removed"
      ],
      "limit": [
          "500"
      ]
  },
  "pathParameters": {
      "proxy": "search"
  },
  "stageVariables": {},
  "requestContext": {},
  "body": null,
  "isBase64Encoded": false
}
```

Note that the field "queryStringParameters" only contains the last value.

You can quite easily handle both via the urijs library:

```js
module.exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  const { path, queryStringParameters, multiValueQueryStringParameters } = event;

  const uriPath = new URI(path);
  if (queryStringParameters) {
    uriPath.query(queryStringParameters);
  }

  if (multiValueQueryStringParameters) {
    uriPath.query(multiValueQueryStringParameters);
  }
  
  // -- snip bootstrap of HAPI server --
  
  // map lambda event to hapi request
  const options = {
    credentials: event.requestContext.authorizer,
    headers,
    method: event.httpMethod,
    payload: event.body,
    url: uriPath.toString(),
    validate: false,
  };

  const res = await hapiServer.inject(options);

  return {
    statusCode: res.statusCode,
    headers: res.headers,
    body:
      typeof res.result === 'string' ? res.result : JSON.stringify(res.result),
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After some logging seems that API GATEWAY parses same query keys as a list in `event.multiValueQueryStringParameters`

So, if you make a request

`GET https://execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/stage/foo?bar=1&bar=2&bar=3`

It will appear in `event.multiValueQueryStringParameters` as an array